# Why singleInstance keep different Stack in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know that Why `singleInstance` keep different Stack in Android for itself.

Docs says :

> A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task

So Task here collection of activities which reside in `Stack`. So according to docs it keep own different `Stack`. Is it right but why it keeps own `Stack` ??

Answer (score 0):

It don't keep a personal `Stack`, it don't have and don't belong to any `Stack` at all.

When it's launched exists only in this moment, if you go back or forward it will not exists anymore.

An example could be:

You have 3 activites `A, B, C`.

If B is `singleInstance` and you will let your use to go to `A -> B -> C` when you press the back button Android will move you back to `A` from `C`, not `B` because it is like it not eists anymore in the `activities stack` (never added to it!).

You should use it only if your application need only one activity.

Comment: If B is singleInstance and you will let your use to go to A -> B -> C when you press the back button Android will move you back to A from C, not B because it is like it not eists anymore in the activities stack (never added to it --- Is this because of `singleInstance` use different `Stack` with different Task ??

Comment: +-(?), Because Android will not add any activity to his stack and don't add it to the stack --- Maybe this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html could help you too.